# How to override NamedSelector class from Mink?

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

I have a symfony 2 project however I have some issue while creating my scenario because tooltip plugin renames title to oldtile, How can I override NamedSelector class from Mink to change some xpath selectors? I need to add "contains(./@oldtitle, %locator%)" to link selector. What would be best approach to override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your FeatureContext extends MinkContext you can try something like this:

```
/**
 * Override NamedSelector
 */
public function setMinkParameters(array $parameters) {
  parent::setMinkParameters ($parameters);
  $selectors = $this->getSession()->getSelectorsHandler();
  $selectors->getSelector ('named')->registerNamedXpath ('field',  <<<XPATH
.//*...
XPATH
      );
 }
```

I.e. put your own selector there.